Simple matrix multiplication - replacement length error
I am trying to do some simple matrix multiplication but I am getting this error:

In ans[i] <- ans[i] + vec[j] * mat[j:i] :
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

The output for y = [30, 30, 30] only contains the correct answer for the first row / first column.
MyMatMult = function(vec, mat){
  ans = vector(mode = "numeric", length = 3)
  
  for (i in 1:ncol(mat)){
    for (j in 1:nrow(mat)){
      ans[i] = ans[i] + vec[j] * mat[j:i]
    }
  }
  
  return(ans)
}

vec = matrix(data = 1:3, nrow = 1, ncol = 3)
mat = matrix(data = 1:9, nrow = 3, ncol = 3, byrow = T)

y = MyMatMult(vec, mat)
print(y)

The desired output should be [30, 36, 42].

What do you think mat[j:i] does? I don't think it does anything sensical here. Maybe you mean mat[j, i]?

Can't you use the %*% operator for matrix multiplication?

j:i is the sequence from j to i. For indexing the rows and columns of a matrix, you need mat[j, i] not mat[j:i].
Correcting this typo:
MyMatMult = function(vec, mat){
  ans = vector(mode = "numeric", length = 3)
  
  for (i in 1:ncol(mat)){
    for (j in 1:nrow(mat)){
      ans[i] = ans[i] + vec[j] * mat[j, i]
    }
  }
  
  return(ans)
}

vec = matrix(data = 1:3,nrow = 1,ncol = 3)
mat = matrix(data = 1:9,nrow = 3,ncol = 3,byrow = T)

MyMatMult(vec,mat)
# [1] 30 36 42

